# Change filenames in directory using R

Tags: r, file-rename

I am trying to rename png files in a directory. Right now they look like this: "E:/S3_Backup_Anna/S3_L1/Subset_S3_L1/subset_pngs/Subset_S3A_OL_1_EFR____20190403T145249_20190403T145549_20190404T211934_0179_043_139_2340_MAR_O_NT_002.SEN3.png"

I would like them to be renamed to just the date in yyyymmdd format, so for the file above it would be just '20190404'

I have figured out how to get the yyyymmdd date:

```
myfiles <- list.files(path = "E:/S3_Backup_Anna/S3_L1/Subset_S3_L1/subset_pngs", pattern = "*.png", full.names = T)

# get date of every file 
startpos <- 73 
yyyymmdd = substr(myfiles, start = startpos, stop = startpos + 7)
```

I've tried file.rename but with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: What about `file.rename` didn't work? Did it throw an error or just not rename the files? Also, what if multiple files have the same date. It might be a good idea to include the timestamp portion in your new name as well.

Comment: it renamed files but they were no longer PNGs, the file type just says "File".. and including the time stamp is a good idea since there are multiples of the same date.

Comment: Ok - be sure to `paste` all relevant file name information, including the path and file extension.

Answer (score 0):

`file.rename` should work for you in this case. However, I would be careful with these functions which can interface with the file system. Be sure you know what you are running before running anything or you may end up doing something you didn't intend on doing.

If you tried `file.rename` and your files did get renamed but without an extension, be sure to include the full name plus extension in your new name. See below for an example.

If I have 3 .png files at C:/Path/To/My/Files with the naming convention image_yyyymmddTHHMMSS.png, the following will work:

```
path <- "C:/Path/To/My/Files"
files <- list.files(
  path = path,
  pattern = '*.png',
  full.names = TRUE
)


startpos <- 37
newName <- paste(path, "/", substr(files, startpos, startpos + 14), ".png", sep = "")

file.rename(from = files, to = newName)
```

Here, I `paste` the path and the new file name and rename those files in `files` to those in `newName`. The return value is a logical vector, so you should see a series of `TRUE` values for each element in `files`.